# maximum recursion error Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to scrape some box scores from ESPN.com and put them in Pandas DataFrame.  I have done similar things in the past in the same manner with out any problems.  However in this case I am getting this error when I try to save the DataFrame.

*RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object*

I get a similar error when trying to save it as a hdf5 table.

Even this snippet gives the same error.  I am pretty confused on why it is doing this?  Is it something to do with the function?

```
url = 'http://espn.go.com/nba/boxscore?gameId=400278773'   
boxurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(boxurl)

tables = soup.findAll('table')
lineScoreTable = tables[-2]
lineScoreRows = lineScoreTable.findAll('tr') 

def GetAwayQTRScores():
    scoreRow = lineScoreRows[1].findAll('td')
    awayQTRScores = []
    for x in scoreRow:
        scores =  x.string
        awayQTRScores.append(scores)
    return awayQTRScores  # returns list

 awayQTRScores = GetAwayQTRScores()

 awayTeam = awayQTRScores[0]
 awayQ1 = int(awayQTRScores[1])
 awayQ2 = int(awayQTRScores[2])
 awayQ3 = int(awayQTRScores[3])
 awayQ4 = int(awayQTRScores[4])
 awayOT1 = np.nan if len(awayQTRScores) < 7 else int(awayQTRScores[5])
 awayOT2 = np.nan if len(awayQTRScores) < 8 else int(awayQTRScores[6])
 awayOT3 = np.nan if len(awayQTRScores) < 9 else int(awayQTRScores[7])
 awayOT4 = np.nan if len(awayQTRScores) < 10 else int(awayQTRScores[8])



 data = {'AwayTeam' :[awayTeam],
    'AwayQ1' : [awayQ1],
    'AwayQ2' : [awayQ2],
    'AwayQ3' : [awayQ3],
    'AwayQ4' : [awayQ4],
    'AwayOT1' : [awayOT1],
    'AwayOT2' : [awayOT2],
    'AwayOT3' : [awayOT3],
    'AwayOT4' : [awayOT4]}


testScrape = pd.DataFrame(data)
testScrape.save('testScrape')
```

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 testScrape.save('testScrape')

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in save(self, path)
     26 
     27     def save(self, path):
---> 28         com.save(self, path)
     29 
     30     @classmethod

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in save(obj, path)
   1562     f = open(path, 'wb')
   1563     try:
-> 1564         pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
   1565     finally:
   1566         f.close()

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

```
print data
```

returns

**{'AwayTeam': [u'LAL'], 'AwayOT4': [nan], 'AwayQ4': [27], 'AwayQ3': [36], 'AwayQ2': [24], 'AwayQ1': [16], 'AwayOT1': [nan], 'AwayOT2': [nan], 'AwayOT3': [nan]}**

Comment: In general, it helps to show the full traceback, or at least which line raises the exception, instead of just the text of the exception.

Comment: I can't see any explicit recursion in your code. Could you please post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation to make your code runnable.

Comment: This exception from `pickle.dump` usually means that you're trying to pickle an object that contains itself (directly or indirectly). Can you `print data` and `print testScrape` and show us the result?

Comment: Also, which parser are you using with BeautifulSoup? Because when I try this with the default `HTMLParser`, it fails to parse. Are you using `lxml` or `html5lib`?

Comment: What's strange is that you can do DataFrame(testScrape.to_dict('foo')).save(), this looks like a strange bug, probably best reporting it as a github issue.

Comment: Hold on, I've got it. `awayTeam` isn't a `str`, it's a self-containing object. Let me write up an answer with more details.

Comment: yea, awayTeam = str(awayQTRScores[0])  fixes it

Comment: @user2333196: You probably want `unicode`, not `str` there; otherwise, if any team name has any non-ASCII characters, you're going to get a `UnicodeError`. (Or, alternatively, you want `awayQTRScores[0].encode('utf-8')` or some other encoding if you really want `str`, instead of defaulting to `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. But you're better off leaving it as `unicode`.)

Comment: As a side note, when I call `save`, I get a deprecation warning telling me to use `to_pickle` instead. I'm not sure when they changed that, but [`save`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.save.html) shows up as part of 0.11.0 instead of 0.12.0, and has no documentation…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception from pickle.dump usually means that you're trying to pickle an object that contains itself (directly or indirectly).

But what object contains itself? When you `print` them all out, they all look fine.

It's `awayTeam` This is a [`bs4.element.NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), which you get by doing this:

```
awayTeam = awayQTRScores[0]
```

You may not notice it from just `print awayTeam` or even `print repr(awayTeam)`, because `NavigableString` is a subclass of `unicode` and doesn't define a custom `__str__` or `__repr__`, so it prints just like a string.

But it also doesn't define a custom pickler, so it uses the default pickler. In general, `bs4` objects aren't designed to be pickled, and many of them can't be. In particular, `NavigableString` is an object that indirectly contains itself. As the docs say:

> If you want to use a `NavigableString` outside of Beautiful Soup, you should call `unicode()` on it to turn it into a normal Python Unicode string. If you don’t, **your string will carry around a reference to the entire Beautiful Soup parse tree**, even when you’re done using Beautiful Soup.

And of course the parse tree contains a reference to the string, which etc. So, this type can never be pickled.

The solution is simple. You wanted a plain old `unicode` string, not a `NavigableString`, so you can just do this:

```
awayTeam = unicode(awayQTRScores[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! I am using Python 3.6.x and wrapping around `str(awayQTRScore[0])` did the trick.