# Multiprocessing BeautifulSoup bs4.element.Tag

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing along with BeautifulSoup but am encountering a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error:

```
def process_card(card):
    result = card.find("p")
    # Do some more parsing with beautifulsoup

    return results


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
cards = soup.findAll("li")
for card in cards:
    result = pool.apply_async(process_card, [card]) 
    article = result.get()
    if article is not None:
        print article
        articles.append(article)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

From what I can gather, `card` is of type `<class bs4.element.Tag>` and the problem may have to do with pickling this object. It's not clear how I'd have to modify my code to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum recursion error Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529708/maximum-recursion-error-python)  The answer is relevant here.  Also, if you can't for some reason follow the advice in the link, another alternative is to use a better serializer, like (my code) `dill` which is used in `multiprocess` (a `multiprocessing` fork with better serialization).  Not sure if it works for `bs4` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pointed out in the comments that one could simply cast `card` as unicode. However, this resulted in the `process_card` function erroring out with `slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`. It turns out that this error has to do with the fact that `card` is no longer a bs4 object and therefore has no access to bs4 functions. Instead, `card` is simply unicode and the error is a unicode-related error. And so one needs to turn `card` into soup first and then proceed from there. This works!

```
def process_card(unicode_card):
    card = BeautifulSoup(unicode_card)
    result = card.find("p")
    # Do some more parsing with beautifulsoup

    return results


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
cards = soup.findAll("li")
for card in cards:
    result = pool.apply_async(process_card, [unicode(card)]) 
    article = result.get()
    if article is not None:
        print article
        articles.append(article)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```